# Javascript syntax issue with returning an object literal

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

```
var Tweet = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: function()
  {
       return
       {
         author: ''
         status: ''
       }
  }
});
```

> according to the syntax it should be

```
 author: '',
 status: ''
```

But this provides an error while the one in code working yet producing no output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have fallen into a trap called [automatic semicolon insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi). Specifically, there **must not** be a newline between `return` and `{`

```
var Tweet = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: function() {
        return { // !!!
            author: '',
            status: ''
        }; // as a convention, I add ; always here, though not strictly needed.
    }
});
```

Otherwise Javascript considers this being 2 statements:

```
return;
```

which just returns the value `undefined`, and

```
{
   author: '';
   status: '';
}
```

which is a block compound statement, where there are 2 [labels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label): `author:` and `status:`, each followed by a no-op string literal expression statement `''`. Adding a `,` after the `author: ''` line makes it a syntax error, as a statement cannot end in a comma / the comma cannot be followed by a label.

Comment: Seriously..?? Yes that worked and moreover I have been coding on C/C++, Java etc and never saw this issue but amazed to read this.

Comment: That's why you should use a linter, like JSLint, JSHint or ESLint.

Comment: There are people who think that relying on ASI is a great thing, well I think it is a cancer :D

Comment: gr8 to know it, this is what happens when u come from a diverse coding background.!